# Resizing another grid row size in WPF

Tags: wpf, grid, resize

I am wondering is there any way to solve this by changing XAML code?

Please look at this sample picture:

[image]

What I wants to do is when user dragging GridSeparater No.1, I want to resize thr 3rd row of grid.

This is because in this application, the first and third rows are variable size, but second one is fixed size.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible with `ResizeBehaviour="PreviousAndNext"` ([Link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.gridresizebehavior.aspx)). This enables you to specify which rows should be affected relative to the GridSplitter.

```
<Grid Width="300" Height="200" Background="Yellow"  ShowGridLines="True">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                  <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1"
                      ResizeDirection="Rows"
                      ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      Background="Black" 
                      ShowsPreview="True"
                      Height="5" 
                      />



</Grid>
```

Comment: Cool - didn't know about ResizeBehaviour. Learned something, thx!

Comment: Nice one!  I found out that the ShowsPreview="True" is pretty important.  If you don't set that property, the GridSplitter behavior will allow you to completely collapse the top row and you can't get it back.  +1

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting both MinHeight and MaxHeight to the same value on the center row which would force recalculation of the bottom section when resizing the top. Something like this:

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="50" MaxHeight="50" MinHeight="50"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>        
    ... other content
    <GridSplitter Height="3" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <GridSplitter Height="3" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
  </Grid>
```